# PHP Require Once Memory Optimization

Tags: php, optimization, process, io, apc

I am currently considering using APC to cache my PHP code into memory so I can optimize my server performance. But one thing that concern me is my code that looks like

```
$a = $_GET['foo']; require_once '$a';
```

My intention of the script above is to reduce number of file need to be loaded (based on request, different class file) so I can improve the IO process. Does APC able to work well in this situation? if so, please help me to recommend your favourite APC.

Thanks.

Comment: I'll tell you now that you shouldn't be doing that (*the piece of code*)

Comment: @Darren Hi Darren, do you think its better to load all of them beforehand?

Comment: `require_once '$a';` will try to load a file called `$a` as a literal; but loading files based on user input of filenames is a very dangerous security hole ready for abuse

Comment: And APC is only for older versions of PHP; modern PHP comes with opCache.... if you're running an old version of PHP, then you may well get a performance boost simply from upgrading

Comment: @MarkBaker Hi I put some prevention for that by using switch case. And for each case different file are loaded. And currently I am using PHP7, do you think this feature will be optimised? Thanks

Comment: If you're using PHP7, then look at the built-in [opCache](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php); there is no APC opcaching for PHP7